# How to achieve Fine-grained Access control when Select ALL columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, security

I am doing some research for my teacher about modifying no-secure queries into secured one. 
For example, a query such as:

```
SELECT family_name, given_name FROM reg_user
INNER JOIN student
ON reg_user_id = student_id;
```

After modified it will look like this:

```
SELECT CASE auth_read_name(reg_user_id, caller_id, caller_role)
WHEN 1 THEN reg_user.family_name END AS family_name,
CASE auth_read_name(reg_user_id, caller_id, caller_role)
WHEN 1 THEN reg_user.given_name END AS given_name
FROM Student
INNER JOIN Reg_User
on reg_user = reg_user_id;
```

In order to achive this type of security, which is whenever there is a column in your select query, you put these columns in a secure SQL function named auth_read_name. But for SELECT ALL, I don't know how to implement this method. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM student;
```

Comment: What exactly is a "no-secure query" from your POV?

Comment: MySQL has a option to set column privileges if that is what your asking here? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#grant-column-privileges

Comment: It is pointless for `SELECT *` because you _have_ to specify which columns require privileged access, and when you specify them there is no point in using `SELECT *`. Also, this is not a practical approach to get privileged column access, so don't sweat too much over it :)

Comment: From my teacher opinion, a student can "SELECT *" but the permission whether he can view all of that columns is based on a security policy file, which is in JSON format.